# Form work's with web but not iOS, event.target returns 'undefined'

Tags: react-native

I've written a login form that works in the browser, but not on Expo Client for iOS.

The ***event.target.id*** and ***event.target.value*** in the ***changeHandler*** method returns 'undefined' on iOS, while it returns the correct values in the browser.

Can anybody explain why?

```
class AdminPanel extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,  
      username: null,
      password: null
    }

    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this)
    this.loginHandler = this.loginHandler.bind(this)
  }

  changeHandler(event){
    let name = event.target.id;
    let value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({[name]: [value]})
  }

  loginHandler(event){
    if(this.state.isLoggedIn){
      this.setState({isLoggedIn: false, username: null})
    }else{
      if(this.state.username == "adm" && this.state.password == "123"){
        this.setState({isLoggedIn: true, password: null})
      }else{
        alert("Login failed")
      }
    }
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.isLoggedIn){
      return (
        <View>
        <Text>Hi {this.state.username}!</Text>
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" onClick={this.loginHandler} />
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      )
    }else{
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Welcome to the admin panel.</Text>
          <Input id="username" onChange={this.changeHandler} placeholder="Username" />
          <Input id="password" onChange={this.changeHandler} placeholder="Password" />
          <Button title="Login" onPress={this.loginHandler} />
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by using ***onChangeText*** instead of ***onChange***, and passing two parameters containing name and text to my new method, ***inputHandler***.

```
inputHandler(id, text){
    this.setState({[id]: [text]})
}
```

...

```
<Input name="username" onChangeText={ (text) => { this.inputHandler('username', text) }} placeholder="Username" />
<Input name="password" onChangeText={ (text) => { this.inputHandler('password', text) }} placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true} />
```

I'm unsure why ***event.target.name*** ***and event.target.value*** aren't accessible from iOS, but something tells me that event's work different in native than from web.